# Iterate over an array of names that start with a specific letter

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, methods

Struggling with this concept.

For example:

```
names = ["Steve", "Mason", "John", "Sarah"]
```

If I want to output some text only for the people whose name start with the letter "S" using the each method, how would i do so?

```
pets = ["Scooby", "Soco", "Summer", "Pixie", "Wilson", "Mason","Baron", "Brinkley", "Bella"] 
(1..9).each {|pets| 
  def start_with? 
    if pets.start_with? "S"
      puts "My name starts with an S for super!" 
    else 
     puts "I’m still pretty special too!" 
    end 
  end
 }
```

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: pets = ["Scooby", "Soco", "Summer", "Pixie", "Wilson", "Mason","Baron", "Brinkley", "Bella"]

(1..9).each {|pets|
def start_with?
  if pets.start_with? "S"
    puts "My name starts with an S for super!"
  else
    puts "I’m still pretty special too!"
  end
end
}

Comment: keep your question clean and shortly. Nobody worries about your expirience, we all here and we all learn. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are defining the same method over and over and over and over again in the loop. You also never even call the method you define. It is not clear what that code is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **[starts_with?](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with%3F)**, you could also check the first letter of each pet name manually:

```
def pets_that_start_with_s(pets_array)
  pets_array.each do |pet|
    if pet[0].upcase == 'S'
      puts "My name is #{pet}, it starts with an S for Super!" 
    else 
      puts "My name is #{pet}, I’m still pretty special too!" 
    end
  end
end

pets = ["Scooby", "Soco", "Summer", "Pixie", "Wilson", "Mason","Baron", "Brinkley", "Bella"]

pets_that_start_with_s(pets)
```

**Output:**

```
My name is Scooby, it starts with an S for Super!
My name is Soco, it starts with an S for Super!
My name is Summer, it starts with an S for Super!
My name is Pixie, I’m still pretty special too!
My name is Wilson, I’m still pretty special too!
My name is Mason, I’m still pretty special too!
My name is Baron, I’m still pretty special too!
My name is Brinkley, I’m still pretty special too!
My name is Bella, I’m still pretty special too!
```

**N.B.** [**upcase**](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/upcase) has been added to ensure there are no issues with capitalization of the pet names.

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach using `each`:

```
names = ['Steve', 'Mason', 'John', 'Sarah']
names.each do |name|
  puts 'some text' if name.start_with?('S')
end
```

You can read more about `each` [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) and `start_with` [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/String/start_with%3F).

(There are probably much faster ways to determine if a string starts with a single character, but I like that this method is very self documenting.)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. this worked for me. How do i submit a block of code like you just did? I cant seem to find how to do it in a comment. I want to show you what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [control expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html):

```
names.each { |name| puts name if name[0] == 'S' }
#Steve
#Sarah
```

This only prints a `name` (via `puts`) *if* the first letter is 'S'. If you don't have to use `each` then you can do:

```
puts names.grep(/\AS/)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by using regular expression:

```
names = ["Steve", "Mason", "John", "Sarah"]
names.each do |name| 
  puts name if name =~ /^s/ 
end
```

Comment: Don't you mean `/\AS/` or `/\As/i`? `^` is beginning of *line* in Ruby, `\A` is beginning of *string*; and you need to watch the case of your `S`.